# Sencha Touch `directionLock` - where am I going wrong?

Tags: carousel, sencha-touch-2

I've got a carousel defined.

```js
Ext.define('rpc.view.bible.indexView', {    
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    alias: 'widget.bible-indexView',
    direction: 'horizontal',
    directionLock: true,
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Bible Reading Plan',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_chapterADayView'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_bibleInAYearView'
        }]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('rpc.view.bible.indexView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

both the `bible-_chapterADayView` and the `bible-_bibleInAYearView` are partial views that extend the Ext.Panel.

They're working as expected, however the scrolling issue that I had in [this bug report](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?152089-Scrolling-and-Swiping-a-Carousel-Card-doesn-t-behave-like-it-did-in-V1.1) still exists even though I have implemented [directionLock](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-cfg-scrollable).

Where am I going wrong with my directionLock implementation?

---

I've also tried the following two methods.

```js
Ext.define('rpc.view.bible.indexView', {    
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    alias: 'widget.bible-indexView',
    config: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            directionLock: true
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Bible Reading Plan',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_chapterADayView'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_bibleInAYearView'
        }]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('rpc.view.bible.indexView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

and

```js
Ext.define('rpc.view.bible.indexView', {    
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    alias: 'widget.bible-indexView',
    scrollable: {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        directionLock: true
    },
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Bible Reading Plan',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_chapterADayView'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_bibleInAYearView'
        }]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('rpc.view.bible.indexView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing, it appears as though it works properly if the `scrollable` is attached to the partialView rather than the carousel.

```js
Ext.define('rpc.view.bible.indexView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
    alias: 'widget.bible-indexView',
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Bible Reading Plan',
            docked: 'top'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_chapterADayView'
        }, {
            xtype: 'bible-_bibleInAYearView'
        }]
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('rpc.view.bible.indexView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});


Ext.define('rpc.view.bible._bibleInAYearView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.bible-_bibleInAYearView',
    config: {

        // ADD THE SCROLLABLE INFO HERE TO ACHIEVE THE DESIRED RESULT
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        },


        items: [{
            html: '<span style="float:right;"><i>Swipe for Chapter a Day</i><div class="x-icon-swipe x-icon-swipe-right"></div></span>'
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            cls: 'x-panel-rpc',
            items: [{
                html: '<h1>Bible in a Year</h1><i>Reading Plan</i>'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            cls: 'x-panel-rpc',
            items: [{
                html: 'Rockin the lower info panel<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>more info<br><br><br><br>end'
            }]
        }]
    },
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('rpc.view.bible._bibleInAYearView ~ initialize');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Comment: The directionLock configuration should always be on the inner-most carousel. It basically tells the framework that inner scrollable area has precedence over the outer-most one.

Comment: And FYI, *all* configs should be within the config: {} block when using Ext.define to create new classes., **always**. If you are creating instances using Ext.create or by passing a object into .add(), then you do not need to put the configurations into the config block.

Comment: @rdougan, so **all** configs meaning `extend`, `alias`, and `initialize` also?

Comment: only configurations should go inside that block. Properties like `xtype`, `alias`, `extend` and `requires` should be outside, as well as all methods, like `initialize`.